# How to put pictures in a single row using semantic view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to put these pictures in a single row using semantic view in drupal7. I just created this view named try and put 2 pictures in it.

[image]

After that, I'm editing this view->format-format->setting->row (this is asking for class attribute, not mandatory) and I don't know what to write in this class attribute.

How do I put these pictures in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Make custom template for that view. Open "Advanced settings" on right side of view editing page and at bottom find "Theming information". There you can see template file suggestions. There if you can see the code of default templates (and copy it to clip board) but you can also see naming suggestions for overriding default templates. So copy code from default template, make from it file with some suggested name, save file in your theme...and clear the cache.
Then change the file as you wish, depending on your needs....

Answer (score 0):

The CSS 'display:inline-block' is a good way to make rows. CSS Flexbox is more difficult to understand, but very powerful. Occasionally, the CSS 'float:left' will do what you need, but it has a tendency to 'log jamb' on differing element heights.

I have used Semantic Views to create continuous, wrap-around content from multiple View rows. I removed the View row element by deleting the default 'div' in the 'Format settings'. That way only a continuous stream of fields appears within the '.view-content' tag.

A custom template is also good.